# Gql query returning unexpected empty with indexed entries

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

A gql query sometimes returns empty and sometimes returns correct results depending on the paramater

```
SELECT Type FROM machinetype Brand='paramaters'
```

the column is indexed and was so before the datastore was populated so it's not that
here is the index serving

```
Type ▲ , Brand ▲
```

Comment: Have you proven that entities match parameter do in fact exist and they have a "Type" value defined ?

Comment: @TimHoffman yes i have

Comment: Have you also checked that this is not an issue related to case-sensitivity ?

Comment: @user3355018 yeah i have

Comment: Based on the query you provided this should be using the index (Brand, Type). It sounds more like this could be an eventual consistency issue.